# Склонение числительного "тысяча"

Tags: числительные

Почему в контексте года в предложном падеже числительное "тысяча" имеет форму:

> в тысяч**а** девятьсот девяносто пятом году

Но когда мы используем предлог *из* в родительном падеже, то это же числительное принимает форму

> группа состоит из тысяч**и** девятисот девяносто пяти человек?

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае вы имеете дело с порядковым числительным *тысяча девятьсот девяносто пятый*. В составных порядковых числительных склонению подвергается только последнее слово: *пятый* принимает форму *пят**ом***.

Во втором примере у вас числительное количественное: *тысяча девятьсот девяносто пять*. В составных количественных числительных склонению подвергаются все элементы: *тысяча девятьсот девяносто пять* становится *тысяч**и** девят**и**сот девяност**а** пят**и***.

Есть очень простой мнемонический прием для запоминания этих правил: составные порядковые числительные ведут себя как ооооочень длинные прилагательные, обозначающие номер чего-либо. Поэтому склоняются они как прилагательные—только окончание в самом конце: *в оченьмногопят**ом** году*.

А составные количественные числительные обозначают количество чего-то, равное сумме всех составляющих, поэтому склоняются все составляющие: *группа из тысяч**и** человек + группа из девят**и**сот человек + группа из девяност**а** человек + группа из пят**и** человек*.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос "почему?" здесь неуместен.

Это не только разные падежи, но и разные числительные. В первом случае - порядковое, во втором - количественное, их совершенно нельзя сравнивать.

К тому же вы немного напутали с формами: тысячи девятисот девяност**а** пяти человек.

Посмотрите на сопоставимые формы.
Количественные
Родительный: (нет) тысячи девятисот девяност**а** пяти человек
Предложный (о) тысяче девятистах девяноста пяти людях ("человеках")

"человек" - используется только как счетная форма, формы для других падежей, кроме родительного, не имеет.

Порядковые
Родительный: (из) тысяча девятьсот девяносто пятого года.
Предложный: (о) тысяча девятьсот девяносто пятом годе.

Что тут еще добавить при такой постановке вопроса - не знаю.